# JSON encoding not working

Tags: php, json, mysqli

Here is my code to encode data in JSON format, but it doesn't work. The result is `[]`. Where is my mistake?

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','project');
$data =array();
if(!empty($_GET['masp'])){
    $masp =$_GET['masp'];
$sql ="SELECT *FROM sanpham WHERE masp='$masp'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if($result){
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $r['masp'] =$data['masp'];
    $r['loai'] =$data['loai'];
    $r['hangsx']=$data['hangsx'];
    $r['tensp']=$data['tensp'];
    $r['img']=$data['img'];
    $r['gia']=$data['gia'];
    $r['nx']=$data['nx'];
 }
}
}
print json_encode($data);

?>
```

Comment: Maybe swap your assignments `$data['masp'] = $r['masp'];`, etc...

Comment: And always use `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: I just edited my answer you have 2 mistakes in your code.

Comment: thank very much , my i swap and it work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting your variables wrong.

In every `while` cycle you get a new `$r` variable that you want to add to your `$data` variable.

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'project');
$data = array();
if (!empty($_GET['masp'])) {
    $masp = $_GET['masp'];
    $sql = "SELECT *FROM sanpham WHERE masp='$masp'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $i = 0;
    if ($result) {
        while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $data[$i]['masp'] = $r['masp'];
            $data[$i]['loai'] = $r['loai'];
            $data[$i]['hangsx'] = $r['hangsx']];
            $data[$i]['tensp'] = $r['tensp'];
            $data[$i]['img'] = $r['img'];
            $data[$i]['gia'] = $r['gia'];
            $data[$i]['nx'] = $r['nx'];
            $i += 1;
        }
    }
}
print json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You make mistake. You should swap variable data with r inner loop, but probably than also will works unpropely. write in while loop $data [] = $r;